# Checking two collections using new Java 8 API streams and lambdas expressions

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have two collections, both of them composed by the same type of object, this type of object has an field, in this case, 'codeType'.

I need to check that in the second collection all the 'codeTypes' are the same that in the first collection, that no additional have been added. I could do it just iterating both collections to get the id's and then checking them.
But as we are using Java 8, I would like to do it using streams and lambdas (because I'm learning about it)

This is so far what I have done:

```
Boolean collectionEquals = CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(oldOrderPositions)
    ? oldOrderPositions.stream()
                       .mapToLong(oldPosition -> 
                                     oldPosition.getCodeType().getId())
                       .allMatch(newOrderPositions.stream()
                                                  .mapToLong(newPosition -> 
                                                                 newPosition.getCodeType().getId()))
   : false;
```

Basically I get both collections I iterate through them to get the Id's and I check that all the id's match. However I'm getting a compilation error saying "allMatch(java.util.fuction.Predicate) in LongStream cannot be applied to (java.util.stream.LongStream)"

Could you please help me? I dont know what I'm doing wrong or what I'm misssing.

Thank you for your time

Comment: I feel that you are reinventing the wheel.. Please use one of Google guava project like this http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#elementsEqual(java.lang.Iterable, java.lang.Iterable)

Comment: @FirstX why should he use a library for this simple issue?

Comment: @dit because it's **not** a "simple issue". It's a non-trivial comparison operation, and streams aren't really well suited for that. Using a Library doing exactly what you want (and that right) is preferrable to creating a DIY bugged utility method

Comment: Indeed, it is not a simple issue, but the issue is not one requiring tons of knowledge and a solution can be found using minimal effort. Using a library for that can be cumbersome. If Guava is already a dependency, I'd use it, but if it's not, I'd write my own version.

Comment: Also, to answer the question itself, you try to apply a `Predicate` instead of a `LongPredicate`. That's what you're doing wrong, in the "compilation" part of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both the other solutions either don't check for doublons or order.

With this solution, you can check that all the ids are present, event if there are doubloons and no matter their positions:

```
return Arrays.equals(
    oldOrderPositions.stream()
      .mapToLong(p -> p.getCodeType().getId())
      .sorted()
      .toArray(),
    newOrderPositions.stream()
      .mapToLong(p -> p.getCodeType().getId())
      .sorted()
      .toArray()
  );
```

Of course, you can refactor this to have methods do the transform but as I didn't know if `oldOrderPositions` and `newOrderPositions` were of the same type, I didn't do it myself. If they are, just do this:

```
static long[] normalize(Collection<OrderPosition> orderPositions) {
  return orderPositions.stream()
      .mapToLong(p -> p.getCodeType().getId())
      .sorted()
      .toArray();
}
...
return Arrays.equals(
  normalize(oldOrderPositions),
  normalize(newOrderPositions)
);
```

Oh yes, and you write that you want to use the streams to do it. I have to say that just because you have a hammer, you won't put everything in a wall with it. Sometimes you need a screwdriver. So this is such a solution, using the appropriate tool for the appropriate problem. Streams are useful for a part of the problem (transforming), but for the comparison, I suggest you take some other and good tools at your disposal, hence the `Arrays.equals()`.

Comment: Makes totally sense what you are saying, thanks. Anyway, I saw at the top of the page that you recommend Guava(which I've never used before) in case is already a dependency in the project, I just checked and it is. Your solution is elegant and I like it but would you then recommend using guava then over this solution, or the opposite?

Comment: This is a matter of personal choice. The advantage to use a solution with Guava is that you don't have the responsibility of testing this code and you're sure it works as expected. If you use Guava, you'd better use two `Multiset<Long>` and compare those instead `Iterables.elementEquals()` (which then becomes the answer of Kocko). On the other side, here you have a complete solution provided to you for your exact use-case, it's your call. The downside is that to ensure exact matching, you have to sort the longs. If your lists aren't really big, it's a nice and good solution. If not, use Guava.

Answer (score -1):

A `Predicate` must take a `Stream` component and return true or false. You probably meant to do something like:

```
public void test() {
    Collection<String> oldOrderPositions = new ArrayList<String>();
    Collection<String> newOrderPositions = new ArrayList<String>();
    Boolean collectionEquals = oldOrderPositions
            .stream()
            .allMatch(code -> newOrderPositions.contains(code));
}
```

Here we stream the olds and insist that they all match the predicate `newOrderPositions.contains` - i.e. every one of the olds is also in the new.

Note that I have greatly simplified your mechanism by just using `Collection<String>`.

Comment: This answer negates all the specifically complex parts of the question, namely 1. the transformation, 2. the need to switch between types and 3. the list-like comparison instead of a set-like comparison.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire - On the upside though - it deals with the actual question which was *why error saying "allMatch(java.util.fuction.Predicate) in LongStream cannot be applied to (java.util.stream.LongStream)"* the answer to which is *use a Predicate*.

Comment: Nope, that's my point 2: the person specifically asks to compare longs and you answer to compare Strings (or whatever object you want), in this case we specifically need a `<primitive>Predicate`. This answers uses that fact nowhere.